# The system should have only trivial solution

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I want to calculate the sum $a+b+c+d$ such that the following system has only the trivial solution.
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0& 5& -9& -c\\ 1&0&0&-d\\5&0&-a&0\\5&9&-b&-9\\0&0&-5&-6\end{pmatrix}$$ I applied Gauss elimination algorithm and I got $$\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0& 0& -d\\ 0&1&-9/5&-c/5\\0&0&1&6/5\\0&0&0&-9+5d+9c/5-6/5(-b+81/5)\\0&0&0&5d+6/5a\end{pmatrix}$$ is this correct so far? how do we continue?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by this "system". You've presented a matrix, not a system.

Comment: I meant the homogeneous, the right side is zero @DonThousand

Comment: Ah I assumed as much, but it should be made clear.

Comment: Is it correct so far what i havr done? How can I calculate the sum a+b+c+d? @DonThousand

Comment: Keep going. Hint: $Ax=0$ admits only the trivial solution when...

Comment: @MaryStar My approach would be as follows: For the only solution to be the trivial solution, the map $v\mapsto Av$ must be injective. So, it is only when it has a left inverse, i.e., the rank is $4$.

Comment: When it is of full rank @SeanRoberson right?

Comment: So the last row must be zero and the one above not zero, right? @DonThousand

Comment: @MaryStar I don't know about that. The correct way to put it would be to say that the $4$ column vectors composing the matrix must be independent. So it's easier to find out when the $4$ column vectors are dependent by setting one of them equal to a non-zero linear combination of the other $3$.

Comment: Can we do that with the last step of Gaussian elimination I applied above? @DonThousand

Comment: @MaryStar You'd want to do Gaussian elimination on the transpose, not the matrix itself.